# Format arbitrary iterable in one template

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

Is it possible to use the built-in string formatting tools of Python 3.4 to repeatedly format items of an arbitrary iterable into one common template?

I.e. I wonder if there is some magic to be able to render a single string like:

```
TEMPLATE = '''Hello {name},

 these are your items:

* {item for item in items}'''
```

using `string.format`

```
OUTPUT = TEMPLATE.format(name='John Doe', items=['foo', 'bar', 123])
```

so that the output will be:

```
Hello John Doe,

these are your items:

* foo
* bar
* 123
```

I know that I can achieve the result with a separate template for the single items and then rendering it into a superordinate format string. But I'd like to do this in one step.

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I feared so.

Comment: What about a jinja2 template?

Comment: @Tobias Thank you. I was looking for something like that. Although it is a python module and not a standard library or builtin function, I think I'll go with that. If you'd like to formulate this as an answer, I'd be glad to accept it.

Comment: @RichardNeumann No problem, glad you liked it. Added an answer just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you go with a Jinja2 template for this use case — it is pretty fast and a lot of people use it.

See http://jinja.pocoo.org for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `'\n* '.join(items)` for this purpose, rather than a second template. I believe the following meets your needs.

```
template = '''Hello {name},

These are your items:

* {items}
'''
formatted_text = template.format(name='sytech', 
                                 items='\n* '.join(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
)

print(formatted_text)
```

The output would be

```
Hello sytech,

These are your items:

* foo
* bar
* baz
```

There is no magical builtin way that you can tell `str.format` to make a bulleted list from your list. However, you could write your own custom formatter to do this, say, if you specify a `'bullet'` format spec, IE `{items:bullet}`. It would be roughly the same as above under the sheets, but you wouldn't need to do `.join` explicitly every time.

```
from string import Formatter
class BulletFormatter(Formatter):
    def format_field(self, value, format_spec):
        if format_spec != 'bullet':
            return super().format_field(value, format_spec)
        return '* {}'.format('\n* '.join(value))

template = '''Hello {name},

These are your items:

{items:bullet}
'''

bullet_formatter = BulletFormatter()
output = bullet_formatter.format(template, name='sytech', items=['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
print(output)
```

The output would be the same as above.

Beyond this, if you want more complicated templates, Jinja may be a good option. A jinja2 template for this may look like

```
'''Hello {{ name }},
These are your items:

{% for item in items %}
* {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
'''
```

Comment: But then `'\n* '` basically *is* a second template.

Comment: @RichardNeumann unfortunately, there's no way `.format` would just know to make your list a bulleted list like that. I updated my answer with another solution that just uses the standard lib and allows passing the list plainly to the  `.format` method of a custom formatter. However, beyond this, you may want to consider an option like Jinja, as other have suggested. Good luck!